# Facebook app_data > Install App > app_data empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having a problem with app_data. I post a feed in my timeline with a link. This link is my app url with app_data aka:

> http://apps.facebook.com/mfanpage/app_123456?app_data=my-very-important-data-here

When the user clicks in the link, he is directed to my app and Facebook ask for some permissions. If user accept all conditions, he is redirected to the app AND my app_data becomes **EMPTY**!

What can I do?
Please HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because when the user authorizes you're app, Facebook redirects the user to the `redirect_uri` that is provided by default by you're which basically does not include the `app_data` which is appended to the url, when the user clicks on the link. So you need to store the `app_data` some how, that when the user authorizes you're app, you can retrieve it again. Maybe go with the `cookies` or HTML5 `localstorage` for storing it temporarily so that you can retrieve it again.